# heroku set document_root

Tags: php, heroku

If I have a directory structure like this:

```
/
/libraries/
/other-nonpublic-stuff/
/webroot/
```

How may I set `/webroot/` as the document_root so that only it's content is served under the URL of my herokuapp?

I think that the `Procfile` might be the way to achieve that, but it's not really documented.
Already tried things like

```
web: php webroot/
```

or

```
web: sh boot.sh webroot/
```

or

```
web: sh webroot/
```

in the `Procfile`, but I always only ended up with `Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected`

When I push a repo with an "index.php" in the root directory it works fine, and a `heroku ps` just shows one web process running "boot.sh", but even then the Procfile is obviously ignored and heroku serves "/" instead of "/webroot". So not really a hint at how I might setup my `Procfile`:

```
Process  State      Command     
-------  ---------  ----------  
web.1    up for 2h  sh boot.sh
```

I logged into the console of my "instance" via `heroku run bash` and did a `cat boot.sh`. It contains this:

```
sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen '$PORT'/' /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf
for var in `env|cut -f1 -d=`; do
  echo "PassEnv $var" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf;
done
touch /app/apache/logs/error_log
touch /app/apache/logs/access_log
tail -F /app/apache/logs/error_log &
tail -F /app/apache/logs/access_log &
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/app/www
echo "Launching apache"
exec /app/apache/bin/httpd -DNO_DETACH
```

So the problem with the `Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected` error (when no .php file is in "/" is obviously solvable by changing `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` to "/app/www/webroot", but thats a) not possible and b) wouldn't solve the issue of using "/webroot" as the docroot. In order to fix that, I also had to modify "/app/apache/conf/httpd.conf".

Any suggestions? :)

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I thought Heroku doesn't work with php. Am I wrong?

Comment: They are silently supporting php since a while on the cedar stack. Since they are cooperating with Facebook. I guess that I might do that with a Procfile, but the usage is nowhere documented for php specifically.

Comment: Not even so silent. PHP is stated here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Comment: It looks like the Procfile is flat out ignored for php apps. :-(

Comment: Do they support Common Lisp silently too?

Comment: @JohnBeynon PHP application==PHP application

Comment: Place an index.php file in the app root directory (even an empty file)

Comment: Hey man! I got the same problem using nginx. But I'm still stuck. Have you had any success?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite to serve content out of "webroot" on Heroku. Try the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /webroot/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webroot/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /webroot/index.php [NC,L]
```

To get around the "no Cedar-supported app detected" error, I just created a new **index.php** file in the root of my repository.  It doesn't matter what this file contains, but I add a few reminders to document these setup details in my own apps.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

It actually boils down to creating a custom boot.sh and pointing Procfile to run that over the default. I've put it all together with a barebones structure over on github: https://github.com/winglian/Heroku-PHP

It includes a hook to use your own conf files too so feel free to play around with it and let me know!

Answer (score 3):

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 webroot/
```

Comment: Create the file Procfile (no extension) in your project root and add this line to it. Then push the Procfile to your Heroku repository. This solution worked for me.